# Повторять запросы пока не будет получен ответ

Tags: python, requests

У меня есть зацикленная программа, которая в начале каждого цикла делает запросы на 3 сайта, получает оттуда данные, иногда какой-то сайт может не отвечать. Мне нужно, чтобы программа после любого неудачного получения данных ждала 5 секунд и отправляла заново запрос и как только получила - сразу продолжала дальше код.

Мой код:

```
session = requests.Session()
while True:
   try:
       a = session.get('a.com',timeout=7).json()
       b = session.get('b.com',timeout=7).json()
       c = session.get('c.com',timeout=7).json()
   except Exception:
       while Exception:
       sleep(5)
       a = session.get('a.com',timeout=7).json()
       b = session.get('b.com',timeout=7).json()
       c = session.get('c.com',timeout=7).json()

# тут дальше идет код, взаимодействующий с полученными данными
```

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы это происходило асинхронно?

Comment: @tonysdev Тут прервать цикл  не могут ))

Comment: @tonysdev спасибо, что откликнулись! Нет, я просто не понимал, как правильно написать такой цикл..

Comment: @СергейШ, ну так с асинхронным подходом все будет намного удобнее, поэтому и уточнил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def res(url, session):
    while True:
        try:
            a = session.get(url, timeout=7).json()
            return a
        except Exception:
            sleep(5)

session = requests.Session()
urls = ['a.com', 'b.com', 'c.com']
for url in urls:
    a = res(url, session)
```

Comment: Блин, спасибо большое, я в первый раз использовал try-except конструкцию и не понимал, что если первая строка будет ошибкой, то вторая не будет читаться даже, спасибо большое за ваш код, он мне очень помог. Хорошего вам дня!