# Как выделить определённое время на выполнение части кода python

Tags: python, оптимизация

У меня есть функция в скрипте, которая большую часть времени работает штатно, но в некоторые моменты она вешается навсегда, а без неё работа программы невозможна. Мне надо каким-то образом сделать так, что бы если она через 5 секунд не начала работать, то она вызывалась заново, или перезапускалась, или итерация в цикле с ней пропускалась или начиналась заново, короче - что бы она не руинила всю программу. Вот код:

```
import requests

def prices_finder(link):
    complete_string = requests.get(link, headers = Headers).text
    complete_string = complete_string[187:]
    minimum_purchase_price = float(complete_string[0 : complete_string.find(" ")].replace(",", "."))
    raw_maximum_selling_price = complete_string[complete_string.find("<tr><th align=")+107:]
    maximum_selling_price = float(raw_maximum_selling_price[:raw_maximum_selling_price.find(" ")].replace(",", "."))
    return [minimum_purchase_price, maximum_selling_price]

for i in url:
    price = prices_finder(i)
    if price[0] < price[1]:
        notification(url.index(i))
```

Вся проблема тут в одной строчке кода: requests.get(link, headers = Headers).text
Может её чем-то заменить, если это возможно? Если нет - то лучше то, что я описал сверху.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1501770/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82/1501775#1501775

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать блоки try except для обработки ошибок. Так же ты можешь с помощью библиотеки requests в методе get есть возможность указать timeout в сек.

Вот исправленный код:

```
def prices_finder(link):
try:
    complete_string = requests.get(link, headers=Headers, timeout=5).text
    complete_string = complete_string[187:]
    minimum_purchase_price = float(complete_string[0:complete_string.find(" ")].replace(",", "."))
    raw_maximum_selling_price = complete_string[complete_string.find("<tr><th align=") + 107:]
    maximum_selling_price = float(raw_maximum_selling_price[:raw_maximum_selling_price.find(" ")].replace(",", "."))
    return [minimum_purchase_price, maximum_selling_price]
except (requests.Timeout, Exception) as e:
    raise RuntimeError(f"Error in  : {link}: {e}")

for i in url:
    price = prices_finder(i)
    if price is not None and price[0] < price[1]:
        notification(url.index(i))
```

Дополнительная документация:

https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts